# How to add items into ActionBar using the default Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So I created the default `NavigationDrawer` Activity in android studio. My issue is that I want to add a small logo or possibly change around with the `ActionBar` but I cant seem to find the xml file which lets me do that.
[What I mean by ActionBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVj8Y.jpg)

HomeActivity.java [This file runs the Navigation Drawer Activity]

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Snackbar.make(view, "WORK IN PROGRESS!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tools) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

app_bar_home.xml [This is the file I think holds a the reference to the top bar]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: please check your menu folder you have two menu file in which name of your draweractivity named file is for you change it. as begin it having only "Setting" named item you can add on it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the right XML, now do something like this in the Toolbar tag. 
 1. Add the image as background in the toolbar OR
 2. Add ImageView tag in the toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbartitle" //either add a background here like this if it helps 
    local:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

OR

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/color_blue"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_header_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@mipmap/header_title" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Hey, if my answer helped you, kindly upvote. Thank you for accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

menu file **named of your draweractivity** in **menu** folder look like below code you can change it as you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Design your own ActionBar, or simply add the proper of

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

in your menu.xml file of the right side menu.....